# Not able to make div center align using display:table

Tags: html, css

I am using display table and table cell verticle-align middle to make div center align. but center div is not positioned center.

Fiddle: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/m0Luns7j/)

Css:

```
.landing-right {
    position: relative;
    padding: 50px 0px;
    float: left;
    display: table;
    width: 365px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -70px;
}
.landing-img {
    height: 420px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 15px solid #fff;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="landing-right">
            <div class="landing-img" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/Cvj2tN3S7ikTu981vJVp&quot;);">                
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with `.landing-right`:

- It has `float: left`. If it needs to be horizontally centered, this CSS rule should not be defined.
- It has `margin-left: -70px` which makes it offset to left for 70px. It is not necessary, and should be removed if the element needs to be horizontally centered.
- No CSS rule is defined to horizontally center the element, the easiest way to implement it is using `margin: 0 auto`.

For vertical center, the code works well.

Here is a code snippet which makes the image centered horizontally and vertically for your case:

```css
.landing-main {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    background: #fefefe;
}
.landing-right {
    position: relative;
    padding: 50px 0px;
    display: table;
    width: 365px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.landing-img {
    height: 420px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 15px solid #fff;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.landing-inner {
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 9px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    padding: 40px 0px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
```

```html
<div class="landing-main">

<div class="landing-inner">
<div class="landing-right">
            <div class="landing-img" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/Cvj2tN3S7ikTu981vJVp&quot;);">
            
            </div>
        </div>
        </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `margin: auto;` for the static width div and remove `float: left;`. It will center the inner one horizontally.
But vertical center align is much harder, you should use something like [this one](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/).

Edit: you did not mentioned that which div was needed to be centered. It was the solution for middle alignment of `.landing-right`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code snippet:

```
.landing-right {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    width: 365px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

In your css class landing-right, you need to make changes and it should be like this-

```
.landing-right {
    position: relative;
    padding: 50px 0px;
    display: table;
    width: 365px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

By keeping float:left, you are making your div stick to the left of the screen and on the top of that with margin-left: -70px; will never let your div come in middle, keep it to auto so div can have the scope with the margin and with no floating of left div will go directly in middle of the screen.